# ORACLE SELECT ID FROM TABLE GROUP BY, ERROR "not a GROUP BY expression"

Tags: sql, oracle, select, group-by, inner-join

im trying Select "UID" from a query about number of repetition of user emails, but i need to get the UID's of users with this Email, im not sure how to do this query on Oracle SQL.

I did this query first:

```
SELECT EMAIL, COUNT("UID") AS NUMREPET FROM USER
GROUP BY (EMAIL) HAVING COUNT (EMAIL) > 1;
```

And the i get something like:

```
EMAIL                       NUMREPET
------------------------   ----------
santiago@com.co                 3    
richard@com                     2    
jorg@hotmail.com                1    
aa@p.com                        1
```

How can i get the UID of query? i tried with

```
SELECT "UID", EMAIL, COUNT("UID") AS NUMREPET FROM USER 
GROUP BY (EMAIL) HAVING COUNT (EMAIL) > 1;
```

But then i got this error "00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression".

To clearfull i want to get something like:

```
"UID"       EMAIL                       NUMREPET
-----   ------------------------   ----------
1787    santiago@com.co                 3    
1788    santiago@com.co                 3    
1789    santiago@com.co                 3    
1000    richard@com                     2    
1001    richard@com                     2           
1687    jorg@hotmail.com                1    
2001    aa@p.com                        1
```

Comment: why are you putting UID inside quotes?

Comment: listagg for the uid might be a good solution if you do not mind them grouped by email as a concatenated list. I see that you do not want to see them that way.

Comment: Becouse is a reserved Word by Oracle SQL.

Comment: The correct answar was use a JOIN sentence in 2 queries.

Thank u a lot for your answers =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could

```
select email, count(uid) as numrepet
  from user
 group by email
 where count(uid) > 1
```

to give you the email addresses that have more that one user id.

You can then join this with your user table to get the user ids that have those emails.

```
select user.uid, user.email, repeatedemails.numrepet
  from user
  join (select email, count(uid) as numrepet
          from user
         group by email
         where count(uid) > 1) as repeatedemails
     on user.email = repeatedemails.email
```

I have not used oracle in a long time, so the specific syntax may be a little off, but you should get the idea from this.

Comment: Yep of course the answer was in use the JOIN sentence.

Thank u it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the UID is a unique value, probably the primary key.

You can just also group by it too.

```
SELECT UID,CORREO, COUNT("UID") AS NUMREPET 
FROM USUARIO 
GROUP BY UID,(CORREO) 
HAVING COUNT (CORREO) > 1;
```

As there only unique values it will keep them separately in rows.

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Well executing this on Oracle SQL show me this result: "Not row selected", is not that i'v expeted

Comment: selecting uid and count(uid) when uid is unique - makes no sense.  Every count would be one.  So count > 1 is always going to be false.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the faster solution but this doesn't seem like the sort of query we'd want to run very often, so perhaps that doesn't matter:

```
SELECT EMAIL, UID, count(uid) over (partition by email) AS NUMREPET 
FROM USER
where email in 
    ( select email from user group by email having count(*) > 1)
order by 1,2;
```